# SQL Server Query Slow When CTE Or Temp Table Used

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL query that takes a date and reports number of pallets that have been scanned into a depot over the last 7 days, but not scanned out by the given date. It takes about a second to run. I need to report this number (using an SSRS report) for the last 14 days. However - when I create either a CTE or a temporary table to generate the dates to report on, instead of rising to 10 seconds (for about 10 dates), it rises to over 3 minutes!

Please advise.

Here's the single date report:

```
DECLARE @back integer
SET @back = 7
Declare @testDate DateTime
SET @testDate = '2012-10-09'
--opening balance query
select count(p.PalletID) as Opening_Balance
FROM [POSTALE].[dbo].[Pallet] p
join [POSTALE].[dbo].[Tracking] t on t.PalletID = p.PalletID
--scan was before indicated day
where CAST(DateAdd(hour, -6, t.TrackDateTime) as DATE) <= @testDate
--scan was after number of days to look back
and CAST(DateAdd(hour, -6, t.TrackDateTime) as DATE) >= dateadd(day, 0 - @back, @testDate)
--scanned into hub (get only the earliest occurence)
and t.TrackingID = (select top 1 tr.TrackingID from [POSTALE].[dbo].[Tracking] tr 
                where tr.TrackCode in ('SCAN OFF TRUNK HUB', 'DAYS') 
                and tr.PalletID = t.PalletID order by tr.TrackingID)
--not scanned out of hub by the indicated day
and (select count(tr.TrackingID) from [POSTALE].[dbo].[Tracking] tr where t.PalletID = tr.PalletID and 
    CAST(DateAdd(hour, -6, tr.TrackDateTime) as DATE) <= @testDate and tr.TrackCode in 
    ('SCAN ONTO TRUNK DEPOT', 'SCAN OFF TRUNK DEPOT', 'SECURITY SCAN AT DEPOT', 'SCAN OFF TRUNK DEPOT', 'SCANNER BROKEN',
    'SCAN ON DEPOT VEHICLE', 'POD ADDED','NO POD ADDED')) = 0
```

Here's the code to join it with a CTE:

```
DECLARE @back integer
SET @back = 7
declare @start_date as date;
set @start_date = cast(getdate() - 14 as date);
declare @end_date as date;
set @end_date = cast(getdate() as date);
WITH DateList AS
(
    SELECT @start_date AS start_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, start_date)
    FROM DateList
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, start_date) < @end_date
)
SELECT
    (select count(p.PalletID) as Opening_Balance
...
,datediff(DAY, d.start_date, getdate()) as daysBack
from DateList d
order by d.start_date
```

..and here's the temp table version:

```
DECLARE @back integer
SET @back = 7
--hours into day that get pushed back to previous day
DECLARE @dayStart integer
set @dayStart = 12
--today + 12 hours as datetime
Declare @date12 as datetime
set @date12 = DateAdd(hour, @dayStart, cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime))
--temporary table to create list of dates to report on
DECLARE @DateList TABLE(
        DayDate DateTime
)
insert into @DateList (DayDate) Select DateAdd(day, - 14, @date12) where datepart(weekday, getdate() - 14) <> 7 and datepart(weekday, getdate() - 14) <> 1
insert into @DateList (DayDate) Select DateAdd(day, - 13, @date12) where datepart(weekday, getdate() - 13) <> 7 and datepart(weekday, getdate() - 13) <> 1
insert into @DateList (DayDate) Select DateAdd(day, - 12, @date12) where datepart(weekday, getdate() - 12) <> 7 and datepart(weekday, getdate() - 12) <> 1
insert into @DateList (DayDate) Select DateAdd(day, - 11, @date12) where datepart(weekday, getdate() - 11) <> 7 and datepart(weekday, getdate() - 11) <> 1
insert into @DateList (DayDate) Select DateAdd(day, - 10, @date12) where datepart(weekday, getdate() - 10) <> 7 and datepart(weekday, getdate() - 10) <> 1
insert into @DateList (DayDate) Select DateAdd(day, - 9, @date12) where datepart(weekday, getdate() - 9) <> 7 and datepart(weekday, getdate() - 9) <> 1
insert into @DateList (DayDate) Select DateAdd(day, - 8, @date12) where datepart(weekday, getdate() - 8) <> 7 and datepart(weekday, getdate() - 8) <> 1
insert into @DateList (DayDate) Select DateAdd(day, - 7, @date12) where datepart(weekday, getdate() - 7) <> 7 and datepart(weekday, getdate() - 7) <> 1
insert into @DateList (DayDate) Select DateAdd(day, - 6, @date12) where datepart(weekday, getdate() - 6) <> 7 and datepart(weekday, getdate() - 6) <> 1
insert into @DateList (DayDate) Select DateAdd(day, - 5, @date12) where datepart(weekday, getdate() - 5) <> 7 and datepart(weekday, getdate() - 5) <> 1
insert into @DateList (DayDate) Select DateAdd(day, - 4, @date12) where datepart(weekday, getdate() - 4) <> 7 and datepart(weekday, getdate() - 4) <> 1
insert into @DateList (DayDate) Select DateAdd(day, - 3, @date12) where datepart(weekday, getdate() - 3) <> 7 and datepart(weekday, getdate() - 3) <> 1
insert into @DateList (DayDate) Select DateAdd(day, - 2, @date12) where datepart(weekday, getdate() - 2) <> 7 and datepart(weekday, getdate() - 2) <> 1
insert into @DateList (DayDate) Select DateAdd(day, - 1, @date12) where datepart(weekday, getdate() - 1) <> 7 and datepart(weekday, getdate() - 1) <> 1
SELECT
    (select count(p.PalletID) as Opening_Balance
...
,datediff(DAY, d.DayDate, getdate()) as daysBack
from @DateList d
order by d.DayDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't described your indexing which could obviously be a huge factor, but one thing I noticed is that your WHERE clause has elements that are not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and could be.

For example, try changing:

```
where CAST(DateAdd(hour, -6, t.TrackDateTime) as DATE) <= @testDate
```

to

```
where t.TrackDateTime < dateadd(hour, 6, dateadd(day, 1, @testDate))
```

You'll need to do a similar thing with this line:

```
and CAST(DateAdd(hour, -6, t.TrackDateTime) as DATE) >= dateadd(day, 0 - @back, @testDate)
```

Comment: Red - thanks for a helpful response, and apologies for the delay responding. I have tried removing all the CAST statements to enable maximum use to be made of the indexes (I'm not allowed to modify the database itself), but it didn't make any difference I'm afraid. The mysterious issue is that the query runs fine for a single date (around 1 second), but when combined with a temporary table or CTE to work for 10 days, it takes an order of magnitude longer (4-5 minutes).

Comment: It's not just the `CAST` the `DATEADD` is a problem too. So, inside the CTE, make sure the column on the left side of `=` is not wrapped with any function, and describe your indexes.

Comment: I think it must be something to do with RAM limits on the server (forcing usage of virtual memory). However, using your tips, and using  a new CTE to limit the amount of searching in the nested subquery, I have got the time down to 1 minute, which I think will be acceptable - thanks for your advice.